# How to configure Packetbeat to sniff "any" devices on Windows?

Tags: elasticsearch, packet-sniffers, packetbeat

The documentation for Packetbeat is pretty straightforward and says it very clearly as stated below

> On Linux, you can specify any for the device, and Packetbeat captures all messages sent or received by the server where Packetbeat is installed.

For the configuration

`packetbeat.interfaces.device: any`

But has absolutely nothing on how to do the same on Windows.

Any idea how?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Packetbeat does not support Mulitple interfaces i.e. `packetbeat.interfaces.device: any` in windows.

However, there is an open issue for enhancement on GitHub for Packetbeat. So there is a chance in future that it may be out there but for now, there is no such thing in Packetbeat to capture all interfaces traffic in windows using `packetbeat.interfaces.device: any`. This feature is only Linux specific.